# Proving whether the series $\frac{\cos(n)}{n}$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I have the infinite sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$$

and I am able to show that it is conditionally convergent by using the Dirichlet Test (and the Lagrange Trig Identity to show the partial sums of $\cos(n)$ are bounded).

However I want to try and prove whether or not it is absolutely convergent. It seems like it isn't, but I have no idea how to prove it either way. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: If it was absolutely convergent I would be really shocked.

Comment: @dREaM In every block of, say, 100 numbers, there is at least 1 for which the cosine term is at least $1/2$. Hence a comparison can be made to (1/200) of the harmonic series.

Comment: @T.Bongers, yeah, I was thinking more along the lines of,  it is impossible for $\cos(n)<\epsilon$ and $\cos(n+1)<\epsilon$, for a suitable $\epsilon$.

Comment: Then we bound it by $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2n}$

Comment: Yep, that works well too.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\frac{|\cos n |}{n } \ge \frac{\cos^2 n }{n } = \frac{1-\cos 2n}{2n}.$$

Comment: This is nice, since we can actually determine the sequence of partial sums!  +1  - Mark

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Informally, for a third of values of $n$, $|\cos n|>1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $\epsilon\in(0,\pi/2)$  the values so that $|\cos(x)|<\cos(\pi/2+\epsilon)$ are the intervals $(k\pi+\pi/2+\epsilon,k\pi+\pi/2-\epsilon)$, with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Taking $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, if we suppose $f(n)<\epsilon$ then there is $k$ so that $n\in(k\pi+\pi/2+\epsilon,k\pi+\pi/2-\epsilon)$. Therefore $n+1>k\pi+\pi/2+\epsilon$ and $n+1<(k+1)\pi+\pi/2-\epsilon$. So $|\cos(n)|\geq \epsilon$.

Using this we have, $\cos(2n)\geq \epsilon$ or $\cos(2n+1)\geq \epsilon$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.

From here $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|cos(n)|}{n}\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2n}=\infty$